# ¿Como subir el formulario editado?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy tratando de editar una notificación desde el panel de administración, el CRUD funciona hasta la parte de editar, en la cual no logro subir la edición de forma correcta, me da un error 401 y se cierra la sesión. Creo que no le estoy pasando bien los datos o no estoy llamando correctamente al servicio para editar. Este es el error:

> ```
> notification:1 Uncaught (in promise) 401
> Error: Abort fetching component for route: "/login".
> ```

```
interface Props {
    showModalEdit: {
        show: boolean;
        id: number;
        title: string,
        body: string,
        actionType: string,
        actionTarget: string
    },
    closeModalEdit: () => void;
        
}

interface FormValues {
    
    title: string;
    body: string;
    actionType: string;
    actionTarget: string;
    
}

export const ModalEditNotification:React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalEdit, closeModalEdit,  }) => {

    
      
    const initialValues: FormValues = {

        title: showModalEdit.title,
        body: showModalEdit.body,
        actionType: showModalEdit.actionTarget,
        actionTarget: showModalEdit.actionType,
      
         
      };

    
      const onSubmit = (values: FormValues) => {
        // setIsLoading(true)
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(values);
            var data = {
                title: values.title,
                body: values.body,
                actionType: parseInt(values.actionType),
                actionTarget: values.actionTarget,
                type: 0,
                pictureUrl: "",
                sender: "xxxxxx",
                creationDate: "2022-11-17T12:58:08.697Z",
                sentDate: "2022-11-17T12:58:08.697Z",
            };
    
            notificationEdit( showModalEdit.id, data)
            .then((response)=>{
                //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log(response)
                // setOpenModal(false);
                // toast.success('Notificacion enviada');
                // setIsLoading(true)
                
            })
            .catch((error)  => {
                console.error(error);
                // setIsLoading(false)
                throw error;
            });
        }, 500);
      };

    return(

        <>
            {showModalEdit.show  ?
            
            <>
            <div id="defaultModal" aria-hidden="true" className="fixed top-0 z-40 inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity "></div>

                <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto ">
                    <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                        <CardBox className="w-full max-w-5xl">
                            {/* Modal header */}
                            <div className="flex justify-between items-start py-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600 mb-4 px-6">
                                <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                                    Editar notificación
                                </h3>
                                <button type="button" className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" onClick={closeModalEdit}>
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            {/* Modal body */}
                            <div className="p-6 space-y-6">
                                <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                                    <form>
                                        <FormField label="Título de notificación">
                                            <Field   name="title" placeholder="Titulo" />
                                        </FormField>
                                    
                                        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                                            <FormField label="Tipo de acción">
                                                <Field name="actionType" as="select" id="">
                                                    {/* <option value={showModalEdit.actionType}>{showModalEdit.actionType}</option> */}
                                                    <option value={''}>Seleccionar</option>
                                                    <option value={'0'}>Ninguno</option>
                                                    <option value={'1'}>Enlace</option>
                                                </Field>      
                                            </FormField>

                                            <FormField label="Secciones">
                                                <Field  name="actionTarget" placeholder="Sección" />
                                            </FormField>     
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <FormField label="Descripción" hasTextareaHeight>
                                            <Field name="body" as="textarea" placeholder="Tu texto aquí" />
                                        </FormField>

                                        <BaseDivider />

                                        <BaseButtons>
                                            <BaseButton type="submit" color="icofcv" label="Aceptar"/>
                                            <BaseButton type="reset" color="icofcv" outline onClick={closeModalEdit} label="Cancelar" />
                                        </BaseButtons>
                                    </form>
                                </Formik>
                            </div>
                        </CardBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </>
            
                :null
               }
            </>
    )
}

////api
export async function notificationEdit(id, info): Promise<Notification> { 
    console.log(getHeaders())
    const response = await fetch(config.apiBaseUrl+`/notification/${id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(info),
        headers: getHeaders()
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
        return data;
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(response.status);
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP 401 es "no autorizado". ¿Quizá los headers no son los correctos? Sin ver el código de `getHeaders()` y sin saber qué espera tu backend es complicado saber qué falla

Comment: Era que faltaban permisos, gracias.